# Search string in an array and return index

Tags: c

I have a problem in my code. After I enter the string I want to search, the program crash.

I have checked my code, but I still could not figure out what went wrong.

Would need your advice.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int findTarget(char *string, char *nameptr[], int num);
int main()
{
int index, index2;
int size;
char *nameptr[100];
char *string[100];

printf("Enter the number of names: ");
scanf("%d",&size);

for(index=0; index<size; index++)
{
    printf("Enter A Name: ");
    scanf("%s", &nameptr[index]);
}

printf("\nEnter a string to search:");
scanf("%s", &string);

index2 = findTarget(string[100], nameptr, size);

if ( index2 == -1 )
{
  printf("\nNo - no such name\n");
}
else
{
  printf("\nYes - matched index location at %d\n", index2);
 }
return 0;
```

}

```
 int findTarget(char *string, char *nameptr[], int num)
 {
int i=0;

for ( i = 0 ; i < num ; i++ )
{

    if (strcmp(nameptr[i],string)==0)
    {
        return i;
        break;
    }
}

return -1;
```

}

Comment: Please format your code in a readable manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code can be generally described as "memory management":

- You do not allocate memory for individual strings
- You are passing addresses of wrong things to `scanf`
- Your use of `scanf` allows for buffer overruns
- You declared `string` as an array of 100 strings, not as a single string
- You are passing `string[100]` to the search function

To fix this, you need to allocate the individual string dynamically using `malloc`. You can use a temporary buffer and then copy with `strdup`, or pre-allocate 100 characters, and limit the `scanf` to it.

Here is a portion of your program that needs changing:

```
char *nameptr[100];
char string[100]; // The asterisk is gone

printf("Enter the number of names: ");
scanf("%d",&size);

for(index=0; index<size; index++) {
    char buf[100];
    printf("Enter A Name: ");
    scanf("%99s", buf); // Note the limit of 99
    buf[99] = '\0'; // Just to make sure it's terminated
    nameptr[index] = strdup(buf);
}

printf("\nEnter a string to search:");
scanf("%99s", string); // No ampersand

index2 = findTarget(string, nameptr, size); // string, not string[100]

for (index=0; index<size; index++) {
    free(names[i]);
}
```

The rest would be just "points for style":

- You do not need a `break` after `return` in the search function
- You do not need to initialize `i` before the loop *and* in the loop
- Printing `\n` at the beginning of a line is discouraged.

Comment: Thank you, it can work already. I have weak knowledge about the memory management issues, which is why I was wondering what was wrong in my coding. Thank you for your help =)

Answer (score 2):

You never allocated memory to `&nameptr[index]`, so using it in `scanf` is undefined behavior. You should try doing a `malloc` before calling `scanf`. Also, you should drop the `&`.

Comment: PS: `return i;  break;` makes no sense.

Comment: @m0skit0 Haha, didn't see that one, rich!

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of `char*`, but when you do a `scanf` into it, you don't actually have allocated a buffer.

Instead, you should first reserve memory for the buffers via something like:

```
for(i=0; i<100; i++) {

    nameptr[i] = malloc(STRING_BUFFER_SIZE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the crashing reason it's because you have not allocated memory for your strings.

Use `char nameprt[100];` instead of `*char nameptr[100];`. What you have declared was an array of pointers to chars and not an array of 100 chars.

And in the scanf you must do like this `scanf("%s", nameptr);`
Reason being, scanf expects a pointer to an array. So there is no reason for the `&` if the variable is already a pointer.